# Pass gridview row data with multiple id datavalues to another webform page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I have a gridview row with a few columns, 3 of them has id values. The first one is the obvious id value from the main table but the other two are datavalues from an id from another two different tables. All merge together in a stored procedures with joins.

I have one page where I add data by filling textboxes and 3 dropdownlists being two of them filled by sqldatasource instead of the normal listitem way, I used the sqldatasource because these dropdownlists had like 50 items and my supervisor told me it was easier because you only change the database and no need for the code.

**EDIT:** To update the gridview is done by another page, this was requested this way. So I made a button for update where I called the index of the specified row. Everything that is inside a textbox is passed with no problem and even dropdownlists that has itemlist on them passed and autoselect themselves, but I cannot pass the dropdownlists that are filled by sqldatasource. The value is not found. Probably is the id of the sqldatasource which goes 0 and fails.

And Im stuck here. Tried different ways to pass the data but no success.

How I can make this dropdownlist read the value from their particular space in the gridview and then show it's value in the dropdownlist space?

Comment: can you please create a sample code here?, what you have, where its fails...

Comment: You have to add a bit more details here. I was reading along just great - we have a gridview (yup - ok!). The gridview has 3 rows (yup - ok!). Then out of the blue some dropdown list appeared in this discussion, and this whole choo-choo train just crashed into a great deep gorge in a wonderful ball of flames. So now  you lost me, and I suspect most readers. This post was oh going so well, but then some dropdown list appear which we don't know is in the grid, the next page, outside of the grid on this page, or even where it comes into play and what it has to do with the grid - we are guessing!

Comment: My bad. I edit it hopefully it is enough. @Aristos maybe I can pass the code I used to get the items from the gridview row?

Comment: Well, you kind of helped, but also made this worse. So you have a few rows in a gridview and one of them is a dropdown list then? You also don't note or mention how you select a row - a button also included in that row? So far, then we click on a button on a row, and we want to pass that info to the next page? (not sure why introduction of the gridview being updated by some other page? (don't matter so far). The question and problem is thus now a gridview - several columns, includes a dropdown and a button in that row when clicked will go to the next page? is that about right?

Comment: I have 3 pages. First page is for data insertion. This one has a few textboxes and the 3 dropdownlists being 2 of them made by sqldatasource from data of different tables. Then second page has only the gridview where the first column has the update button. And third page is for the update data which is a exact copy of the insertion page but this one grabs the value of the row from the gridview and auto insert them in their own textboxes and dropdownlists boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, how to pass things to another page? More ways of doing this then there are flavors of ice cream.

Ok, so we have a select button on the gridview.

So, I assume something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
   <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button"
                    CommandName ="Select" PostBackUrl="~/HotelGridResult.aspx" />
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Now look VERY close at that button we added to the grid.

We use:

```
CommandName= "Select"
```

VERY important. This tells asp.net to CHANGE and SELECT the current row. If you don't have that command, then the row does not select.

Next important:
We have the postback URL set to jump to the NEXT page.

This allows and means that the button will not ONLY jump to that page, but "postback URL" also means to PASS THIS page!!!!

And since we pass the page to the next, then in the page load event (and ONLY in the FIRST page load even, then we are FREE to get, grab values from the calling page!!!

in this case, we will get and grab the gridview row selection!!!

So, our code can look like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
if (IsPostBack == false)
{
    GridView gv;

    gv = Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("GridView1");
    GridViewRow gvRow = gv.SelectedRow;

    string s;

    s = "Selected index = " + gv.SelectedIndex + Constants.vbCrLf + gvRow.Cells(1).Text + "," + gvRow.Cells(2).Text + gvRow.Cells(3).Text;

    TextBox1.Text = s;
}
}
```

So remember:
We can only pick up the previous page in the first page load - first time only.

We can ONLY pick up the previous page if we set the postback url of the button on the previous page. and we can ONLY pick this up in teh first load (is postback = false) of the load event (one try and go at this - only first time page loads).

you can also use a server.Transfer in the button code (server side - gridrow index changed) if you for some reason don't want to use/have the postback url in teh button, but the above is the least hassile.

As you can see in above, we are now free and able to pick up not only the gridview from the previous page, but DUE TO the commandName="Select" this ALSO casued the gridview row to change for us!

And thus now we can both pick up previous page and thus also pick up the gridview row the user selected.

At that point you can pick the the cells() of that row, or you may well need to use findcontrol if you using custom templated controls like I did with the button.

Comment: Oh nice explanation. Hmm will it work if for example if City its datavalue is inside a dropdownlist by sqldatasource? Not inside the gridview but in the update page.

Comment: I don't know what "update page" means? We are on a web page, we click on the button, we jump to next page (how can there be anything more then that????). At that point you can pick up the previous page (but you can't pick up say previous previous page). If that drop down is is on this page that jumps to the next? Sure, you can pick it up with findcontrol like the gridview. however, if the drop down was before the page that is jumping due to the gridrow button click? Then you have to pass that dropdown to this current page, or put the value into session() as that will persist though all pages

Comment: Any and all controls and their values on this page with the grid vide that jumps to the next? yes, with the "previous page" you can use find control and can pick up any value of any control from previous. As noted, previous page is ONLY valid here because we set postback url. If you don't use post-back URL, then previous page is NOT valid. As noted, you can also use server.Transfer("some web page") in code behind to jump and this also works like using post-back URL, So server.Transfer means you don't have to set post-back URL when you do this. You can only pick up previous page on first load.

Comment: So I guess to answer your queston? Yes, if a drop down or text box on the page that jumps to next via post-back URL? yes all controls can be picked up via FindControl.